# How do I stop an app from requesting to "control this Mac using accessibility features"

Tags: security, accessibility

I am currently getting requests:

> "daemondo" would like to control this computer using accessibility features

The problem being, that I have not heard of this app, and I cannot recall installing it. I can deny it from gaining access, but it keeps reprompting.

Running `which daemondo` reveals `/opt/local/bin/daemondo`, yet `port provides /opt/local/bin/daemondo` cannot identify a port that it belongs to.

- What is `daemondo`?
- How can I stop the prompts?

On the latter question, I guess the answer involves finding the spawning process, killing it, and removing it, so any hints on identification are more than welcome.

Comment: The simple fix was to `sudo mv $(which daemondo) $(which daemondo).bak`, but I'll keep the question open as I'd like to know where this thing is coming from and if there is more clean-up to perform.

Answer (score 2):

`daemondo` is part of MacPorts itself. To quote from the documentation:

> To support launchd, a program named daemondo is provided by MacPorts
> base that serves as an adapter between launchd and daemons
> (“executable” StartupItems) or traditional Unix startup scripts that
> start daemons (“script” StartupItems).

ref https://guide.macports.org/chunked/reference.startupitems.html